# add plot object to figure in axis

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to add a plot inside a figure, something like this:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize =(10,5))
plot1 = customized_function(x1, y1) # any plot object
plot2 = customized_function(x2, y2) # any plot object
axs[0] = plot1 # adding the plot1 to the figure
axs[1] = plot2 # adding the plot2 to the figure
```

But I can't find a way to add `plot1` and `plot2` into the figure. I have been looking everywhere for a solution and the solution doesn't fit my needs. The solution I find is this:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)
fig.suptitle('Axes values are scaled individually by default')
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2.plot(x + 1, -y)
```

However, the plots I want to add are already done.

Any suggestions?

**Reproducible code:**

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
def customized_function(y_train, prob_train):
    fpr = dict()
    tpr = dict()

    fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_train, prob_train)
    roc_auc = dict()
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)

    # make the plot
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr)
    plt.title('ROC curve and AUC')
    plt.show()
    

y_train = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1])
prob_train = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.1,0.1,0.8,0.9,1])

y_test = np.array([0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1])
prob_test = np.array([0.1,0.4,0.2,0.5,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.8,0.3,0.1])

customized_function(y_train, prob_train)
customized_function(y_test, prob_test)
```

Comment: I cant really get your point. After `ax2.plot(x + 1, -y)`, you can still customize the plot styles such fontsize, ticks, labels, text and etc. The first code block above is NOT the standard way to plot in matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to write plotting function is to pass the reference to the axes to the function:

```
def function_customized_plot(x, y, ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    (...) # rest of your code here

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize =(10,5))
function_customized_plot(x1, y1, ax=axs[0])
function_customized_plot(x2, y2n ax=axs[1])
```

Comment: It runs, but it doesn't work. It still returns a figure with two empty plots.

Comment: Since you didn't provide the code for your plotting function, I can't help any further

Comment: I apologize then as I thought it was simple. I added a reproducible code.